# How to use raw data file without editing it

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have a JSON file which contains a multi-dimension array of information.  I would like to use it to populate a web page, but I don't want to manually amend the content of the file.  I can't include a snippet of the file, due to the contents, but it looks like:

```
{"something":{"value1":0,"value2":0,"value3":10000,"value4":"*"}}
```

I can use the data if the file is formatted like:

```
var data = [{"something":{"value1":0,"value2":0,"value3":10000,"value4":"*"}}]
```

but as stated I don't want to manually add the declaration of "data" (and the squared brackets).

How can I do this within my html page? Do I need to find a way to prepend and append, saving in a new file, or is there some other way?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: You could read the file as text/string using JS and then append/prepend your square brackets to that. And then use JSON.parse( json_string ); to turn it into a JSON object.

Comment: @ShanieMoonlight can I do that without the use of a server?  the file will be in the same folder, and I don't seem to be able to see a way without a server (XMLHTTP request).

Comment: Some answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file

Comment: That page has had 1.4m views - I think that I'm half of them!  Every option that I've tried on that page gives me the "CORS" error.  Are there any other ways that you could suggest?

Comment: Is the file on the server or on the users PC?

Comment: it will be in the same folder on a local pc - this is just a simple web page build to create an easier view of the data, to be used only by the owner of the pc, so not held on separate server

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to read a file from the users PC using based on this: [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29176118/2826614)

HTML:

```
  <input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'>
```

JS:

```
var openFile = function(event) {

  var input = event.target
  var reader = new FileReader()

  reader.onload = function(e) {

    const jsonTxt = e.target.result.toString()
    const jsonTxtArray = '[' + jsonTxt + ']'
    console.log('obj', JSON.parse(jsonTxtArray))

  }

  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);

}
```

Here's a working example: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shanieMoonlight/56hpn0rL/2/)

Comment: `.toString()` is unnecessary,. Why wrap it brackets when just can use `[JSON.parse(text)]`? and why use the FileReader at all when you can as well just do: `[await new Response(file).json()]`

Comment: would there be a way to do it when the page loads - so automate it for a set file name - so for example, the file to use will always be called "thisfile.txt" - or something like that?  That way, when the text file is updated, they could just refresh the web page and it will use the latest version of the file.

Comment: @Endless Can you post your answer. I haven't used `Response(file)`. I'd like to see a better solution. ToString is probably unnecessary, I was just being cautious

Comment: @ShanieMoonlight  I'm not sure this or my my answer would be the correct answer... but here is a jsfiddle that would pretty much do the same thing that you are doing: https://jsfiddle.net/1n3f7pmx/

Comment: @Endless I like it!

Comment: @Steve_G I'm not sure how to do that